# Error while sending Mail from contact form with simple php and bootstrap-

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email, contacts

```
<?php $errName = $errMessage=$errHuman=$result=$errEmail="";  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$human = intval($_POST['human']);
$from = 'بخش ارتباط با ما';
$to = 'info@iranrtn.com';
$subject = 'پیام جدید';

$body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

// Check if name has been entered
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}

// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';

}

//Check if message has been entered
if (!$_POST['message']) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
}
//Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
if ($human !== 5) {
    $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
}// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success text-center">با تشکر از شکیبایی شما به<a href="index.html"> خانه </a>بازگردید.</div>';

    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}  } ?>

<body style="font-family: yekan">  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1 class="page-header text-center">جهت ارتباط با ما فرم زیر را پر کنید.</h1>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">نام</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="نام و نام خانودگی" value="">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="ssss">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">پیام</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="پاسخ شما">
                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div >
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="ارسال" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div >
                    <?php echo $result; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> </div> </div> </body>
```

I try to send Email from contact form of my website to my host mail (info@domain.com) I check every part of my code the email address was created correct the action is Ok but when i push the send button it shows an error i did not have this problem on Windows host but not on a Cpanel host is there any configuration for mail setting? ps : this contact form work on another site.

the file contact.php is here >>
all in one php file
here is the contact form : http://iranrtn.com/contact.php

Comment: What is the error?  You need to check the server logs and php logs to see what's happening.  `mail()` only returns a bool true if its successful

Comment: There is no such thing as a "CPanel host". Contact your hoster, and find out what you actually have. Ask for the mail log.

Comment: That is not necessarily true about cpanel.  Some providers allow you to upload a custom php.ini to your web root to override certain settings, in either case, you'll need to check with your hosting provider to find out how to proceed.